# Help with DC Gearmotor Specs

Tags: motor, torque

I need help understanding the specs of [this RS Pro DC Geared Motor, Brushed, (RS: 238-9670)](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/dc-geared-motors/2389670/).  It has an operating range of 4.5-15V and a nominal voltage of 12V, so does that mean that it provides 0.59Nm of torque and 84RPM when it's running at 12V?

If the voltage is reduced, the torque will go up and RPM will go down and if it's increased the RPM will go up and torque will go down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will provide 0.59Nm of torque and 84RPM when it's running at 12V.

If voltage is reduced, RPM will go down and vice versa.

However, torque does not go up or down according to voltage. Torque is related to current. Higher torque is needed to lift heavier load, so the motor draws the required amount of current it needs from the battery to produce the torque needed.